# jQuery add content after a <div></div> when a <span> inside that <div> is clicked

Tags: jquery

In the following code, I'm trying to add content after the `<div></div>` which contains the `<span>`, when a `<span>` inside that `<div></div>` is clicked.

**This is the place:**

```
<div id="container">

    <div class="h1" data-id="1">Teachers <span class="add" data-id="US01">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="h2" data-id="2">Who is your favorite Math teacher? <span class="add" data-id="US02">Add New</span></div>
        <br>
    <div class="h1" data-id="8">Restaurants <span class="add" data-id="US10">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="h2" data-id="9">Which is your favourtie restaurant in town? <span class="add" data-id="US20">Add New</span></div>

</div>
```

So, If I were to click the `<span>` `add`, content needs to be added after the `<div>` which contains the `<span>`. Problem is, right now it adds content after the `</span>`. How can I get it to add after the `</div>` that contains the `<span>`

**Here's the rest of the code I'm trying out:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Side bar poll thingy</title>
<style type="text/css">
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.no-like {
    color: blue;
}
.first{
    display:block;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/scripts/jQueryCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add").click(function() {
        var idPri   = $(this).data("id");
        //var data = 'id='+idPri+'&sec='+idSec;
        console.log($(this).data('id'));
        $(this).after("<div class='newbox'>I'm new box by append</div>");



        if(idPri) {
            // ajax call
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"demo.php",
                data:data,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend:function(html){
                    // To do later
                },
                success: function(callBack){

                },
                error: function(page_data){

                },
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <div class="h1" data-id="1">Teachers <span class="add" data-id="US01">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="h2" data-id="2">Who is your favorite Math teacher? <span class="add" data-id="US02">Add New</span></div>
        <br>
    <div class="h1" data-id="8">Restaurants <span class="add" data-id="US10">Add New</span></div>
    <div class="h2" data-id="9">Which is your favourtie restaurant in town? <span class="add" data-id="US20">Add New</span></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.parent()` method:

```
$(this).parent("div").after("<div class='newbox'>I'm new box by append</div>");
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tafy7/)**</kbd>